# Will this antenna even help?

Tags: antenna, wifi, pcb-antenna, esp8266

I am using ESP8266 (esp-07) in a project. I was facing connectivity/range issues with my old router. So, I am planning to use a PCB antenna with esp. This is how it looks:

[image: PCB antenna]

Here is the mechanical drawing:

[image: Mechanical drawing]

I am wondering whether it will work. I have two reasons to be doubtful:

1) I don't have any knowledge about antenna design. So, I am not sure whether this antenna design is suitable for 2.4 GHz.

2) Antenna might be helpful only while transmitting. So it will work when ESP is trying to send some data to router but will not work when router is trying to send some data to ESP.

I want to know what you guys think. Should I try this out or is it totally worthless? Also, what will be more helpful - using this antenna on ESP or getting a better router itself?

EDIT:

Here is a link to the antenna:

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Signalwell-2-4ghz-5-8ghz-4_60187711114.html

Comment: How about a link to the antenna?

Comment: @Andyaka - Fixed that. Sorry for not providing the link.

Comment: Doesn't your ESP8266 have an antenna on the PCB ? I do not expect this other antenna to have much better performance. Also,  is there a connector to connect the external antenna ? If not you should not just solder the cable directly, this is RF, it needs to be done properly otherwise you make performance worse. If your ESP8266 has no provisions for an external antenne, forget about it because chances are you will make it worse.

Comment: @FakeMoustache - There is a chip antenna on the ESP and there is a connector given to add an external antenna. This antenna can mate with that connector. The ESP will go inside a switch board which is three sides metal. I was planning to take this PCB antenna out of the switchboard after connecting it to ESP in order to improve the range.

Comment: I wouldn't trust an antenna that doesn't have a data sheet (proper pdf)

Comment: Probably you have an ESP module like this: https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi126znlbjJAhUBkA8KHUEwCIkQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftronixlabs.com%2Fiot%2Fesp8266-esp-07-wifi-board-with-full-io-chip-antenna-and-full-external-antenna-bundle-australia%2F&psig=AFQjCNEUPHDaYHHw1w6BxqdubV53psLHsw&ust=1448973700103573  Then I still have more faith in that chip antenna. The one from Alibaba does not seem to be designed by someone without antenna knowledge. It's just a spiral on a board. Too simple if you ask me.

Comment: @FakeMoustache - I couldn't open your link. [This](http://img.banggood.com/thumb/view/2014/xiemeijuan/12/SKU188843/SKU188843-1.jpg) is the module I am talking about. Regarding this antenna, I was a little skeptical too because all articles and app notes I found had a little different design such as inverted F, tilted whip, meander etc but not like the design that I posted.

Comment: It is the same module. Good. I think the design of the Alibaba antenna is the "odd one out", inverted F or pifa is what I would expect. I have yet to see a "proper" WiFi antenna that looks like the Alibaba one, indicating to me that that is not a good design. I would not waste my money on it.

Answer (score 1):

The link that you provided does show that it can work in the 2.4GHz frequency. And for the full duplex doubt you have. There can be many ways you can fix that. A time tokening is a most simple method of doing so. Many wifi modules have dedicated antennas for transmission and reception. Even if the antenna is one, the wifi module that you speak of is a simple one that can be interfaced to a MCU(so probably UART or SPI is the interface between the WIFI ASIC and MCU, so no fancy high speed).

The mnodule itself has a patch antenna on the PCB. So, how do you intend to connect the u.FL to this module ?

Comment: [This page](http://store.hackaday.com/products/esp8266-07-module-with-u-fl-chip-antenna-fcc-ce-certified) shows ESP as well as an antenna. You will find an extra connector given on ESP module. That's where I am planning to connect the antenna.

Comment: My bad. I looked at a different module.https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678.

Comment: ESP has around 12 different variants. That sparkfun thing is ESP-01. That's the most basic version. ESP-12E has the most GPIO pins.